# The "grep -w" command is not working

Tags: grep

I have the input below:

```
csdi_d_trs_proc_uxs1        26 24
csdi_d_tdp_process_uxs1     28 32
```

I only need the line which contains `proc`. When I use:

```
grep proc filename
```

both lines are output, so I tried using `grep -w proc filename`, but no output is getting displayed.

How can I get the line which has only `proc` but not `process`?

Comment: why not to use `grep '_proc_'` instead of just `grep 'proc'`? Option `-w` is for words and `_` is not a word delimiter.

Comment: and how this line `csdi_d_trs_11proc-_uxs1 26 24` should be treated?

Comment: @Roman presumably it's out of scope for the question so the result of any solution would be undefined for this value.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `-w` flag for `grep` will make the given expression match only whole words.

A "word" is a string of "word characters" surrounded by "non-word characters" (or start/end of line).

The issue in your case is that `_` (underscore) happens to be a "word character", and does therefore not serve to delimit the word `proc` as a word on its own.

Instead of using `-w` with `grep`, use a pattern that explicitly delimits the word by `_`:

```
grep '_proc_' filename
```

Alternatively, use `[^a-z]` instead of `_` if you want to delimit the word by anything that is not a lower-case alphabetical character:

```
grep '[^a-z]proc[^a-z]' filename
```

Note that this won't recognize `proc` as a word at the very start/end of a line though.

Answer (score 4):

> `-w, --word-regexp`
>                 Select only those lines containing matches that form whole words. [...] Word-constituent characters are letters, digits, and the underscore.

The underscore is valid as part of an identifier in most programming languages (at least C, Perl, shell), which is probably why it's considered a "word-character" here.

One way to match just word would be to use the negative look-ahead and look-behind tests that Perl regexes provide. Here `(?<![a-z])` means "not preceded by a lower case character, and `(?![a-z])` similarly for what comes after. The beginning and end of the line aren't lower case characters, so this will match `proc` even at the beginning:

```
pcregrep '(?<![a-z])proc(?![a-z])' filename
```

Or with a grep ERE, taking the beginning and end of a line explicitly into account:

```
grep -E '(^|[^a-z])proc([^a-z]|$)' filename
```

(I'm not sure which one of those is prettier.)

If you have natural-language text, `[[:alpha:]]` might be more correct than `[a-z]`.

But of course, just grepping for `_proc_` is easier, if you know the underscores will be there.

Comment: grep '_proc_' filename worked for me.Thanks kusal for your reply